# Grails: How can I access application configuration from a command-line script?

Tags: grails, command-line, configuration, groovy

I need a custom command-line task in my grails app, so I have created a script using `grails create-script my-script`.

From that script, I would like to access some of the application's config properties. Normally you can do this via `grailsApplication.config`. However, it seems `grailsApplication` is not available from within the context of a command-line script. The following script....

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("Init")

target(main: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    println  grailsApplication.config.mysetting
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

...yields (when run as `grails my-script`):

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property:
                                      grailsApplication for class: MyScript
```

I also tried `ConfigurationHolder.config`, which just returns null.

So how can I access application config from a script launched from the command-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to pull in the **boostrap targets** and depend on them, as shown below. Note that the application context object is called **`grailsApp`**, and not `grailsApplication` at this stage.

```
includeTargets << grailsScript('_GrailsBootstrap')

target(main: "The description of the script goes here!") {
    depends checkVersion, configureProxy, bootstrap
    println  grailsApp.config.mysetting
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

You might also be able to use the [run-script](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-script.html) command. This didn't work for me, because it tries to initialise a Hibernate session. My app uses mongodb as a primary datastore, which [requires that you uninstall the Hibernate plugin](http://springsource.github.com/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html#2.1%20Using%20Mongo%20Standalone) - so run-script fails.

Answer (score 2):

1) Refer to **_GrailsPackage** at the top of your script:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript('_GrailsPackage')
```

2) Depend on compile and createConfig targets described in **_GrailsPackage**

```
target(main: "Your main") {
    depends(compile,createConfig)
    println "My value: ${config.my.config.value}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't yet write a comment, so I'm posting an answer.

I think the solution using the *_GrailsPackage* script suggested by snowindy is to be preferred. The reason is that using bootstrap actually boots the application, which means connecting to the database, executing the BootStrap.groovy, etc. Just using *_GrailsPackacke* with the *compile* and *createConfig* dependencies just requires a compilation run.

Dependending on what your script does this is probably what you want to have. In my case I generated some SQL scripts that can be customized via settings in the Config.groovy, so booting the app was just slowing things down.

Cheers,
Ben